# Eclipse Android Device not showing up | Can't find RNDIS driver

Tags: android, eclipse

Under Eclipse my Android device is not showed up. Also, if I go under Device Manager it shows that there's no driver for RNDIS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. Go to device manager
> 2. Find the Device with the little ? and then maybe a yellow !
> 3. Right click that device and select Update Driver
> 4. When the window pops up (on Windows 7 32bit), select Browse My Computer for driver software, on the next screen click on the
>    bottom that says, LET ME PICK.
> 5. It will ask you the device type
> 6. Go down to Network Adapters
> 7. It asks you to select manufacturer, skip Microsoft and select Microsoft Corporation
> 8. Select Remote NDIS based Internet Sharing Device
> 9. Hit next, proceed to install
>
> You should be set. I hope that helps.

Works exactly the same on Windows 7 x64

Thanks to Android1126

Source http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=12758233&postcount=18